# Database join using SQL Server 2012 as a loginless user?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

If I have two databases 'dbA' and 'dbB' using a normal account I know I can run a query such as

```
SELECT * 
  FROM dbA.dbo.TableA a
  JOIN dbB.dbo.TableB b ON a.columnA=b.columnB
```

But I can not figure out how to grant permissions to a loginless account

```
USE dbA;
CREATE USER [test_user] WITHOUT LOGIN WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
GRANT SELECT ON DATABASE::dbA TO [test_user];
```

I receive an error when trying to give select permission to the loginless user 'test_user' on the other database.

```
GRANT SELECT ON DATABASE::dbB TO [test_user];
```

Is it possible to do a database join using loginless users? If so what should the grant statement look like for setting correct permissions?

Comment: @M.Ali I don't think it matters. I believe the a user without a login can only exist at the database level. Creating the same user in another database is a completely distinct account and won't get mapped.

Answer (score 1):

A user without a login can only access other databases that have the guest user enabled.  You might consider using a certificate-mapped user instead if you have a cross-database requirement.  See http://www.sommarskog.se/grantperm.html for code.

Answer (score 0):

Users exist at the database level.  Only logins exist at the server level.

I believe you can create a view in dbA like so:

```
use dbA;

create view dbB_TableB as
select *
from dbB.dbo.TableB;
```

And you can then assign SELECT permissions for the user in dbA to the view.